# upload pictures to picasa in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to upload photos to picasa using C# in WP7. Where I can download the picasa API's for WP7. It would be really nice if there is an example on how to authenticate and also upload photos.

Answer (score 1):

There are some examples available:

- [Getting started with OAuth in C#](http://blog.stevienova.com/2008/04/19/oauth-getting-started-with-oauth-in-c-net/)
- [Uploading picture to picasaweb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577846/uploading-picture-to-picasa-web)

Please share your solution if you manage to get it to work

Comment: I tried downloading the .Net google API's for WP7. But I could not use them directly. I m getting an error saying that the libraries are not compiled using windows runtime. Could you please let me know how to use the libraries